# SQL Server pattern matching

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, case, sql-like

I am joining several different tables in SQL Server.  The join is based on a loosely defined code set that has been entered slightly differently in the tables I'm joining.  The same code has been entered in one of the following equivalent variations of stripping leading zeros or adding a letter suffix:

- 09D01 (most common)
- 9D01
- 09D01a
- 9D01a
- 9D1
- 9D1a

I've created a join using a case expression with an evaluation for each variation:

```
...left join code
    on case
        when btfd.proqa like '[0-9][0-9][A-Z][0-9][0-9]' then 1
        when btfd.proqa like '[0-9][A-Z][0-9][0-9]' then 1
        when btfd.proqa like '[0-9][0-9][A-Z][0-9][0-9][A-Z]' then 1
        when btfd.proqa like '[0-9][A-Z][0-9][0-9][A-Z]' then 1
        when btfd.proqa like '[0-9][A-Z][0-9]' then 1
        when btfd.proqa like '[0-9][A-Z][0-9][A-Z]' then 1
        else '0'
        end = '1'
```

The join works as presented, but seems very "clunky".  Is there a more efficient way or standard pattern to accomplish the same result?

Comment: Just trying to use LIKE in a JOIN is clunky and `CASE` prevents the server from using indexes. At the very least *remove* the `CASE` and use `OR` to combine the conditions. A JOIN condition that only uses one table is strange too as it produces the cartesian product of the filtered rows with the other table.

Comment: `slightly differently in the tables I'm joining` in that case it's better (by a million times) to clean up the data in the table and join on the clean columns. You can use a computed and indexed column for this.

Comment: Aside: Mixing data types without reason is a habit to avoid. Since a `case` expression can only return a single data type, it will follow the rules for [data type precedence](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/data-type-precedence-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) and convert the `else` value from a string (`'0'`) to an `int` to match the other values (`1`). Then you compare the result to another string (`= '1'`) just to force another conversion. Don't do that.

Comment: you can create a side-table where you put all the variations you use, and LEFT JOIN against that side-table, that will simplify your case immensely

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what it'll do to the shape of your plan, but something like this might work for you:

```
DECLARE @Table TABLE (DirtyColumn NVARCHAR(6));
INSERT INTO @Table (DirtyColumn) VALUES
('09D01'), ('9D01'), ('09D01a'), ('9D01a'), ('9D1'), ('9D1a');

DECLARE @Sales TABLE (ID INT IDENTITY, Date DATE, Code NVARCHAR(6));
INSERT INTO @Sales (Date, Code) VALUES 
('2023-06-01','09D01'),('2023-06-02','9D01'),('2023-06-03','9D01a'),('2023-06-04','9D1'),('2023-06-05','9D1a'),('2023-06-06','09D01a');


SELECT *
  FROM @Sales s
  INNER JOIN @Table t
    ON t.DirtyColumn = s.Code;
```

Using an `APPLY` might be an option too, but it could potentially bloat your plan.

If we had a little more code to go out, it would easier to provide a more complete answer.